# MySQL: Combine chunks of timespan with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, timespan

I have a table with timespan chunks. 
A timespan has a start date and a length in days

1. There are timespans in the table that do not overlap, e.g.:
   2012-01-01 + 5 days  and  2012-05-01 + 3 days
2. And there are timespans that overlap, e.g.:
   2012-01-01 + 5 days  and  2012-01-03 + 3 days
3. However, I am mostly interested in those occurring in a row, e.g.:
   2012-01-01 + 5 days  and  2012-01-06 + 3 days  and  2012-01-09 + 13 days

I need a query that selects 1. and 2. normally (each entry as a single row).
Case 3. must be selected combined as a single row, e.g.
**2012-01-01 + 5** days  and  2012-01-06 + **3** days = **2012-01-01 + 8** days
**2012-01-01 + 5 days**  and  2012-01-06 + **3** days  and  2012-01-09 + **13** days = **2012-01-01 + 21 days**

Here is an example DB:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chunks` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`start` date NOT NULL,
`length` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM ;


INSERT INTO `chunks` (`id`, `start`, `length`) VALUES
(1, '2012-01-01', 5),
(2, '2012-05-01', 3),
(3, '2012-01-03', 3),
(4, '2012-01-06', 3),
(5, '2012-01-09', 13);
```

Is this possible with MySQL? Or is it better done with Java later on?

Comment: Are you looking for a query that will find all the instances of #3? Or all the dates + any overlapping blocks?

Comment: I need a query that changes this:(1, '2012-01-01', 5),
(2, '2012-05-06', 3) to: (x, '2012-01-01', 8). In other words: IF the start date of one chunk equals the end date of another chunk THEN combine them to one chunk with MIN(start date) and SUM(length)

Comment: You could self-join to get pairs of overlapping records but to combine n-rows of overlapping you'll probably have to use @vars. http://www.mysqldiary.com/user-defined-variables/   - if it were me I'd fall back to a post-select solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not sufficiently constrained, because two intervals could arrive at the same date.  In that case, how do they get merged?

```
2012-01-01 5
2012-01-02 4
2012-01-06 3
```

In other words, this problem is equivalent to traversing a tree, from the leaves first.  In general, to solve this problem, you need to step out of SQL-only solutions, such as a loop.

If there are gaps between the sequences -- that is, no overlaps -- then the problem is solvable in SQL.  One way is with a calendar table.  The second is to use complicated SQL to determine if a time period should be merged with the next, then find the first non-merging time period, and then group the results to combine the periods together.

Comment: In my context, overlapping as in your examples or in #2 is excluded by other parameters. Therefore you can ignore overlaps. Can you provide an example query for your calendar solution? Thanks

Comment: @MartinHo . . . I understand that it is "excluded" from your output.  However, when multiple periods overlap, you don't know which one to choose.  Or, you might have two chains starting with each one.  Can all overlapping periods be removed?  In your example 2012-01-03 not only overlaps with 2012-01-01, but it also has a common next member, of 2012-01-06.

Comment: yes, sorry for the confusion. forget about the overlaps. How can I found out that two or more are in sequence without gaps? Thank you